# MySQL Select list In Array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, select

Each Article can have unlimited categories.

Categories are saved in the database like this

example article_category:   '1','3','8'

OR

example article_category:   '2','3'

So when I search for a listing under, lets say category 3

```
$category_id = $_REQUEST['category_id'];  //3
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM ARTICLES WHERE article_category = '$category_id'";
```

If it were just one the above would work fine.

I hate to say it but I'm completely lost.. Would I use IN ?

Comment: @Michael: Don't use values from `$_REQUEST` directly in your SQL query.  You should [escape](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) them or use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: @Einacio I haven't had any good responses. I might be asking my questions wrong

Comment: @Rocket This is how I request, but I didnt think I needed to show the full request. $new_keyword = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST["new_keyword"], ENT_QUOTES);  $new_keyword = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","", $new_keyword);

Comment: then rework your questions so that the community can help you better, as it is recommended

Comment: You can also select the answer that helped you most, one must not 100% answer your question.

Comment: @Einacio thanks, I was already using "LIKE" but I felt like there was a better way to do this in('') or something. I dont know, thats why I asked

Comment: @Michael: You cannot use `IN` here.  `field IN (1,2,3)` is the same as `field=1 OR field=2 OR field=3`, which won't work here.

Comment: @Michael: Does your `article_category` contain quotes?  Is it saved as `1,2,3` or as `'1','2','3'`?

Comment: &Rocket  it is saved like this '1','2','3' but it doesn't need to have the quotes. It does need the commas

Comment: I should say to, the "LIKE" option does not work. It returns category 3, 13 and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

= (equals) check against the complete string. what you want to do could be done using LIKE and the % comodin (it's like * for files in `dir` or the like)

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM ARTICLES WHERE article_category LIKE \"%'$category_id'%\"";
```

however, i reccommend that you normalize the database and have categories as a subtable

Comment: Question about like. if I have this '1','3','8','33 would like pick up the 3 and the 33?

Answer (score 1):

The way I would implement this is by creating a table for categories, which you probably already have. Something like:

```
cat_id    cat_name
1         animals
2         sports
3         locations
```

Then create a table to link articles to categories. Something like:

```
table artcat
article_id    cat_id
1             1
1             3
2             1
2             2
2             3
```

The above table basically replaces the field article_category you have currently. In the above example

```
article 1 is linked to categories 1 and 3
article 2 is linked to categories 1, 2 and 3
```

And when you need to get all the articles for a given category, all you would run a query like:

```
SELECT article_id FROM artcat WHERE cat_id=3
```

You could even do a join with articles database to output the article titles if you wish.

I hope this helps. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`FIND_IN_SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) here, but it may not be very efficient.  I suggest that you change your table structure and follow @jdias' answer.

If your `article_category` is saved as `1,2,3`:

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM ARTICLES WHERE FIND_IN_SET('$category_id', article_category)";
```

Or if it's saved as `'1','2','3'`:

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM ARTICLES WHERE FIND_IN_SET('\'$category_id\'', article_category)";
```