# How do I query mysql data with array

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables `colorcode` & `users`

`colorcode`

```
ID colorid  colorname
------------------------
1  1        yellow
2  2        black
3  3        red
4  4        white
```

`users`

```
ID userid  colorid
------------------------
1  1        1,2
2  2        3,4
3  3        1,3,4
4  4        1
```

How do I retrieve & query individual `colorid`

```
$aa = $db->query("SELECT * FROM colorcode"); 
$colors = array();
   while ($colordata = mysql_fetch_assoc($aa)) {
   $colors[] = $colordata["colorid"];
}
```

Let's say I want query which users have `yellow` color & what it's the statement should I use for  `users`

```
SELECT .. FROM users
WHERE colorid ....
```

Comment: You should [normalize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your `users` table. Create a new relationship table called `user_colors`, because the way you have it, it's not even in the [1NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form).

Comment: You should probably change your structure. Storing comma separated values causes far more headaches than it solves. @Shef Thanks to A Level computing, I know know what 1NF is. Hooray!

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7448245/mysql-select-list-in-array

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038590/alternative-to-like-clause-in-mysql/7038639#7038639

Comment: By the way, Using a column named "ID" is not necessary for the tables if "userid" and "colorid" can be used as primary keys for unique identifiers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE colorid LIKE "%1%"
```

---

**But** what I would really do is make a link table from users to colors:

> usersToColors:

```
ID userid  colorid
------------------------
1  1        1
2  1        2
3  2        3
4  2        4
...
```

Then you could do:

```
SELECT * FROM users u, usersToColors utc
WHERE u.userid = utc.userid 
      AND utc.colorid = 1;
```

Or even:

```
SELECT * FROM users u, usersToColors utc, colors c
WHERE u.userid = utc.userid 
      AND utc.colorid = c.colorid
      AND c.colorname = "yellow";
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a bad design... since you're trying to access the individual color_ids in the user table, but have stored them as a comma-separated list, you canot have the database do a normal join for you - you've killed off the main point of using a relational database by making it impossible to for the database to do the relating for you.

However, since you're on mysql, you're in luck - mysql has a function for cases like this:

```
SELECT users.ID, userid, GROUP_CONCAT(colorcode.colorname)
FROM users
LEFT JOIN colorcode ON FIND_IN_SET(colorcode.ID, users.colorid)
GROUP BY users.id
```